# Finding a digit with Javascript

Tags: javascript, flowchart

I have a  4 digit number. How can I get the second digit on the right.

It worked my way...but is there a better one?

```
function SecondNumberOnTheRight(number){
  var number;
   number = parseInt(number%100)/10;
   newNumber = parseInt(number);
   console.log(newNumber);
}
```

SecondNumberOnTheRight(1259);//5

Comment: Which is your way?

Comment: The one I wrote.  SecondNumberOnTheRight();

Answer (score 3):

```js
function SecondNumberOnTheRightY(number){
var t0 = performance.now();
  var number;
   number = parseInt(number%100)/10;
   newNumber = parseInt(number);
   var t1 = performance.now();
   console.log("Your took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
}
function SecondNumberOnTheRightM(number){
   var t0 = performance.now();
   var num = number.toString();
   var res = Number( num.charAt(num.length-2) );
   var t1 = performance.now();
   console.log("Mine took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
}
SecondNumberOnTheRightY(1588565);
SecondNumberOnTheRightM(1588565);
```

change number to string , then use charAt to get char in your desired index.. Ok check performance also.

Comment: my bad. performance is not same, feels like it doesn't depend on code.. :x

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution.

```js
const SecondNumberOnTheRight = num => `${num % 100}`.slice(0, 1);
  
console.log(SecondNumberOnTheRight(1259));
console.log(SecondNumberOnTheRight(987654321));
```

Comment: This method is slower than OP method.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Slower? Even if it is, the differences are so minimal that we can just ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast it to a string and use `substr`:

```js
var num = 1259;
function secondNumberOnTheRight(num) {
    return num.toString().substr(2,1);
}
console.log(secondNumberOnTheRight(num)); // '5'
```

And if you need a number as the result use `parseInt(num, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is the simpliest one, but you can also write in the following way:

```
console.log(parseInt(number/10)%10);
```

Here is short example:

```js
var number=1259;
console.log(parseInt(number/10)%10);
```